# Apache + Railo setup on mac

Tags: apache-2.2, railo

I've setup a Railo Express + Apache + MySQL on my mac. I believe there is still something wrong with Railo-Apache settings, because I have to add port (8080 for me) in order to pull up the site. Please advice what can cause this issue. Feel free to ask questions if I gave too little information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is configured to listen on port 8080.
You need to reconfigure it to listen on the standard HTTP port (80).

Consult the documentation for the package you installed, and/or the [Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) for information on how to configure Apache.